# C# how to detect operators in string to calculate?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

Say a program receives an input string `"8*10+6/2"` and should output `83`, in this case. how to handle the operator?

I can chop the string into individual strings, then detect whether it is a number or operator. If it is an operator I can convert it to `int`. But I have no idea how to handle the operator so that the calculation works.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Regexes and String splitting are your friends :)

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a [parser](https://gppg.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @JhonAlx: regex and string splitting will definitely not be your friend here. Writing (or searching for) a parser will be an easier way to handle things.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I said it because i worked on something like [this](https://github.com/JhonAlx/tc-solutions/blob/master/Main/src/SimpleCalculator.java) training in TopCoder. My solution does not have operator precedence analysis because of the problem statement, but with some work it would work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)-"trick":

```
double result = (double)new DataTable().Compute("8*10+6/2", null);
```

The following arithmetic operators are supported in expressions:

```
+ (addition)
- (subtraction)
* (multiplication)
/ (division)
% (modulus)
```

More informations in: [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) at *Expression Syntax*.

Comment: John Ryann, @Tim Schmelter's answer is what you'd use in real life, but for school they might want you to do some trickery with `if (string.equals("/")){use division...} else if (str.equals("*")...`. It depends on whether this is an exercise from an intro to programming course or a C# language course. You could also try using char comparisons and a switch statement. The exact implementation is within your abilities. Good luck! :)

Comment: This answer saves the question. +1